# C# CustomFormat DateTimePicker in RTL Language

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, datetime-format, right-to-left

I got `DateTimePicker` control.
I used the following code to set the format of the control:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";
```

it worked with one problem. My computer culture language is RTL language (hebrew), so I see the format of the time in the control like that "mm:HH" althought I wrote "HH:mm". It caused by the RTL culture, So I tried two ways to solve it but none of them worked / worked completely.

I tried:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

and it didnt work at all.

I also tried to detect wheter its RTL language or not by using this code:

```
CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
```

and then to reverse the format string from "HH:mm" to "mm:HH" (if its rtl language) but then I discovered another problem - in XP if its RTL language it will write the right format.. so yeah I can detect if its XP or not but I think this is too much code for simple need...

Is there easier solution?

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was DTP breakage for RTL languages in Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.  The KB article [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2030901), the forum thread that got that ball rolling [is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8adaad55-b502-4191-b40e-85e065847a27).  Not exactly a slamdunk for your case but compelling nonetheless.  Try the hotfix it links to.

Comment: It require me and my clients to install the update. Is there another way to use this update without installing it?

Comment: Yeah, no problem.  Burn the hotfix to a DVD and put the disc of top of the machine.  You have to keep it warm though, it stops working below 15 degrees Celsius.  A common problem with hot fixes.  For crissake.

Comment: Well, Thank you. I guess I'll have to use my way (detectin the OS and do w/e I need).